# PHP Compare "YYYY-MM-DD" with task urgency colour option (yellow/orange/red... table cell)

Tags: php, css, date

I am trying to create a task tracking web application that shows a table of current tasks and their sequence of progress. Tasks are logged in a MySQL database. From some other questions here I have so far got as far as how to compare "YYYY-mm-dd" to "YYYY-mm-dd" with the following code:

```
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")); // "2016-08-06"
$startDate = $row['start_date']; // "2016-08-04" from the database

if ($row['started'] == 1) { // database tinyINT is either "1" or "0"
    if(strtotime($today) < strtotime($startDate)){
        echo '<td class="green_tick" style="background-color:yellow;">&#10004;</td>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<td class="green_tick">&#10004;</td>';
    }
} else echo '<td></td>';
```

I want to be able to give visual indication of a task being overdue for attention (by table cell background-color) compared to today's date.

So if a task is marked as started ($row['started'] == 1), the table cell just displays a green tick (&#10004).

If a started task is 2 days old, the table cell with the green tick is style="background-color:yellow" (indicating that maybe I should have a look at this task).

If a started task is 4 days old, the table cell with the green tick is style="background-color:orange" (indicating that I should really start looking at this task).

If a started task is 6 days old, the table cell with the green tick is style="background-color:red" (indicating that I should seriously have a look at this task before things get out of hand).

So the question is, how can I do multiple date comparisons for: $today, $today - 2 days, $today - 4 days, and $today - 6 days?

Thanks for all the answers, they were all helpful. I ended up going with the following:

```
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
$startDate = strtotime($row['start_date']);
$diff = $today - $startDate;

if ($row['started'] == 1) {
    if ($diff >= 172800 && $diff < 345600) {
        echo '<td class="green_tick" style="background-color:yellow;">&#10004;</td>';
    }
    elseif ($diff >= 345600 && $diff < 518400) {
        echo '<td class="green_tick" style="background-color:orange;">&#10004;</td>';
    }
    elseif ($diff >= 518400) {
        echo '<td class="green_tick" style="background-color:red;">&#10004;</td>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<td class="green_tick">&#10004;</td>';
    }
} else echo '<td></td>';
```

Maybe not worthy of a poetry award, but it works OK for me. Although this is the answer I arrived at, to be fair it was derived from ideas from the other answers.

Comment: may I add that it may be worthwhile changing the icon as well - this will help color-blind people to see the differences. Something to consider anyway?

Comment: May I add Ryan... as a disabled one hander for 16 years. The world doesn't stop and wait for people with disabilities. The reason I became the fastest one handed typist on the face of the planet, is because I realised this a few years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the number of day between now and the date the task started.

```php
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")); // "2016-08-06"
$startDate = strtotime($row['start_date']); // "2016-08-04" from the database

if ($row['started'] == 1) { // database tinyINT is either "1" or "0"
    $daysPassed = floor(($today-$startDate) / (60*60*24));
    $color = '';

    if ($daysPassed >= 6)
        $color = 'red';
    elseif ($daysPassed >= 4)
        $color = 'orange';
    elseif ($daysPassed >= 2)
        $color = 'yellow';

    if ($color)
        echo '<td class="green_tick" style="background-color:' . $color . ''';">&#10004;</td>';
    else
        echo '<td class="green_tick">&#10004;</td>';
} else
    echo '<td></td>';
```

You can also calculate the number of days as following:

```php
$today = new DateTime(); // "2016-08-06"
$startDate = new DateTime($row['start_date']); // "2016-08-04" from the database

$daysPassed = $startDate->diff($today)->format("%a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a PHP Switch, here's a link to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Example code:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$startDate = new DateTime($row['start_date']);
$elapsed = $startDate->diff($today)->format("%a");

if ($row['started'] == 1) {
    echo '<td class="green_tick"';
    switch ($elapsed) {
        case 2:
            echo ' style="background-color:yellow;"';
            break;
        case 4:
            echo 'style="background-color:orange;"';
            break;
        case 6:
            echo 'style="background-color:red;"';
            break;
        default:
            echo '';
    }
    echo '>&#10004;</td>'
} else echo '<td></td>';
```

One thing strikes me as odd about this, namely it seems to me that you would want these statuses to apply to the ranges in between the specified values as well in which case you'd want to use the following:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$startDate = new DateTime($row['start_date']);
$elapsed = $startDate->diff($today)->format("%a");

if ($row['started'] == 1) {
    echo '<td class="green_tick"';
    switch ($elapsed) {
        case ($elapsed <= 3 && $elapsed > 1):
            echo 'style="background-color:yellow;"';
            break;
        case $elapsed <= 5:
            echo 'style="background-color:orange;"';
            break;
        case $elapsed >= 6:
            echo 'style="background-color:red;"';
            break;
    }
    echo '>&#10004;</td>'
} else echo '<td></td>';
```

I would also recommend that instead of applying the style tag to each element you might want to consider creating a css class for each color and applying that class instead. It would most likely result in smaller page sizes if you use a reasonably compact class name.

Answer (score 0):

First define your array of days/colours, and then iterate over it like this:

```
    $today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $startDate = strtotime("2016-08-04");
    $daysDiff = round(($today-$startDate)/86400);
    $colors = array(2=>'yellow', 4=>'orange', 6=>'red');
    $output = '<td></td>';//assign default value in case no condition is met
    if ($row['started'] == 1){
        $output  = '<td class="green_tick">&#10004;</td>';
        foreach($colors as $days=>$color){
            if($daysDiff <= $days){
                $output = "<td class='green_tick' style='background-color:$color;'>&#10004;</td>";
                break;//if the condition is met, you break the loop
            }
        }
    }
    echo $output;
```